# Is DriveApp.getFiles() the equivalent of DocsList.getFiles()?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using the importFromCSV script and it ran fine the first time but I got a warning in the script editor that the DocsList.getFiles() is deprecated and should find an alternative. I tried to directly swap out with DriveApp.getFiles() but then the script times out on that line now.

Is DriveApp.getFiles() not interchangeable with DocsList.getFiles()? If not, what should I be using? Or is there something else I am missing that causes the timeout?

```
function importFromCSV() {
  var fileName = "0B2n-RwpLExXnaXRBWG1aT3NLbm8";

  var files = DocsList.getFiles();
  var csvFile = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    if (files[i].getId() == fileName) {
      csvFile = files[i].getContentAsString();
      break;
    }
  }
  var csvData = CSVToArray(csvFile, ",");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  for (var i = 0; i < csvData.length; i++) {
    sheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no

DocsList returns an array of files while DriveApp returns a [file iterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator). See [documentation here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getFiles()).

But when I see your code, you don't get the file by **name** but you use the **ID**... so you could simplify your code using `DriveApp.getFileById('0B2n-RwpLExXnaXRBWG1aT3NLbm8')` that will immediately return the right file without iterating or looping...

Comment: Thanks Serge. Yes, DriveApp.getFileId works to return the file name. However this then does not work with getContentAsString(), it is expecting some other type of return. The file[i] return after looping just shows in the logger as "File". Is there some other process I need to run on the result of DriveApp.getFileId before I can use getContentAsString()?