# Install add-ons on every document in a folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

I have made an add-ons for Google app scripts . Now I want to add it in every document in one folder. How can i do that?

In this tutorial https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/docs, it only uses for one document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your add-on was published to Google Marketplace/Chrome Web Store and you installed it from there, and you are the owner of all the docs in the folder, that add-on should be available in your docs under Add-ons menu. I think it's the same for domain-specific add-ons as well (have no way to check it at the moment).

If you just created an add-on in a doc-bound script, then the add-on will only be available in that doc. To add it to other docs, you will have to copy your script into those docs manually - there is no API way to do it.

Comment: I have another question , could you explain the different between the method DriveApp.getFolders() and DocsList.getFolders()? Thanks

Comment: please avoid follow up questions, this is unclear and not useful for the community. btw, this has been asked very recently :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26032285/is-driveapp-getfiles-the-equivalent-of-docslist-getfiles/26033082#26033082