# What is the alternative to getContentAsString() from DriveApp API?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that will get the content from a .csv file in Google drive and pull it in to a Google Sheet. The script uses the DocsList service which is deprecated. The below works as required but I want to transition the DocsList components to DriveApp to ensure it works for the foreseeable future.

The main issue I see is that the getContentAsString() method does not appear to be available for DriveApp. Is there a direct alternative to getContentAsString() or a combination of other elements that can achieve the same outcome as the below script?

```
function importFromCSV() {
  var fileName = "0B2n-RwpLExXnaXRBWG1aT3NLbm8";
  var FileId = DriveApp.getFileById("0B2n-RwpLExXnaXRBWG1aT3NLbm8");
  var files = DocsList.getFiles();
  var csvFile = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    if (files[i].getId() == fileName) {
      csvFile = files[i].getContentAsString();
      Logger.log(files[i]);
      break;
    }
  }

  var csvData = CSVToArray(csvFile, ",");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  for (var i = 0; i < csvData.length; i++) {
    sheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DriveApp file object has a `getBlob()` method, the blob object has a `getDataAsString()` method... You can chain both methods to get a **string content**.

Below is the full code, simplified as it should (there were other inconsistencies in your initial code , as already mentioned in your [former question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26032285/is-driveapp-getfiles-the-equivalent-of-docslist-getfiles)).

```
   function importFromCSV() {
      var id = "0B2n-RwpLExXnaXRBWG1aT3NLbm8";
      var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);// get the file object
      var csvFile = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();// get string content
      Logger.log(csvFile);// check in the logger
      var csvData = CSVToArray_(csvFile);// convert to 2D array
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
      sheet.getRange(1,1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);// write to sheet in one single step
    }

    function CSVToArray_(strData){
     var rows = strData.split("\n");
     Logger.log(rows.length);
     var array = [];
      for(n=0;n<rows.length;++n){
       if(rows[n].split(',').length>1){ 
       array.push(rows[n].split(','));
       }
       }
    Logger.log(array);
    return array;
    }
```

Comment: I've been using: `   while (files.hasNext()) {
     var file = files.next();
       var theContent = file.getAs('text/plain').getDataAsString();
       Logger.log(theContent);
 };`

Comment: Serge, thanks so much for this. I did see the getBlob and getDataAsString in the references but had no idea how to use them so thanks for that. The simplification on the CSVToArray function is also great.

Comment: Sandy, thanks for your suggestion. Looks like getAs('text/plain') works just as well as getBlob(), in this particular circumstance anyway.

Any idea how to get rid of the quote marks on either end of the string? They are not in the csv file so I assume the getDataAsString() adds that.