# Importing CSV data into GSheets. Headers, rows and columns not alligned

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm attempting to import a CSV file into a Google-Spreadsheet using Google-Apps-Script.

I started with [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/docslist_tutorial) tutorial which I found online. I ran into some difficulties with it and some searching brought me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26133841/what-is-the-alternative-to-getcontentasstring-from-driveapp-api) SO post. By coincidence it looks like the OP was trying to do the exact same thing as me so I adapted the answer to my own needs.

There is some dummy data in my GDrive in a csv file called "cabbages"

```
cabbages    bananas apples  carrots
0.006423706 0.34396684  0.446078488 0.58361487
0.099325843 0.534487652 0.391869452 0.637707661
0.610335498 0.053597109 0.700272752 0.693743589
0.861971984 0.023244272 0.611117465 0.574383772
0.55353014  0.380635698 0.763808189 0.785754755
0.760590319 0.451239949 0.738469185 0.643373164
```

And here is the script I adapted to my own needs:

```
// add the CSV menu. Might change this to be an automatic update based on date
function onOpen() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var csvMenuEntries = [{name: "Load from CSV file", functionName: "importFromCSV"}];
  ss.addMenu("CSV", csvMenuEntries);
}

function importFromCSV() {
      //var id = "cabbages";
      var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("cabbages.csv");// get the file object
      var csvFile = file.next().getBlob().getDataAsString();// get string content
      Logger.log(csvFile);// check in the logger
      var csvData = CSVToArray_(csvFile);// convert to 2D array
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
      sheet.getRange(1,1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);// write to sheet in one single step
    }

    function CSVToArray_(strData){
     var rows = strData.split("\n");
     Logger.log(rows.length);
     var array = [];
      for(n=0;n<rows.length;++n){
       if(rows[n].split(',').length>1){ 
       array.push(rows[n].split(','));
       }
       }
    Logger.log(array);
    return array;
    }
```

The script runs and imports data. The trouble is, the resulting data look like this:
[image]

Data are all in row 1 and are not in the correct columns like in the original file. I had hoped the resulting data would look exactly like cabbages.csv.

How can I edit my script to match columns?

Comment: Hoping to set up a lot of automated reporting in Gsheets by having our devs place a csv file to drive automatically each morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSVToArray_ function is expecting data cells separated by commas, and lines terminated by \n (newline).

These assumptions don't hold up in your case, so you need to determine which characters to split on instead.

To split on an "Carriage Return" (\r) rather than "Newline" (\n) change:

```
var rows = strData.split("\n");
```

to

```
var rows = strData.split("\r");
```

To split on whitespace instead of commas (such as if your columns are tab-separated)

Change:

```
if(rows[n].split(',').length>1){
    array.push(rows[n].split(','));
```

To:

```
if(rows[n].split(/\s/).length>1){
   array.push(rows[n].split(/\s/));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I made the change and got this error message "Incorrect range width, was 1 but should be 8"
I then got some imported data that was a row of strange symbols. They look like question marks inside of a diamond. Any ideas?

Comment: sorry, you needed to edit two lines of code, not just the IF, see my clarified answer.  Question marks inside of diamonds indicates characters your system can't display, not sure why you'd be getting that outcome, but hopefully the adjusted answer fixes that also.

Comment: OK. I made the update. Now I get this error: "Incorrect range width, was 2 but should be 3". I also get a row of data with 3 cells populated: A1:2, B1:0, C1: "obj" (Unquoted).

Comment: Also, I just tried downloading the csv file and opening in a text editor. Looks like it is comma separated. I'm not sure if it's just that when I opened in GDrive it looked like a tsv?

Comment: Hmm, that's stumping me.  If you can determine whether your source file is delimited by spaces or tabs, you could try adjusting the calls to split to use the correct character (eg  split('\t') for tabs, or split(' ') for spaces.  

Incorrect range width means that the Array you are writing to the sheet doesn't match the size of the range you've selected, so for some reason you are getting different lengths when you split each row of data on /\s/

Comment: So the raw file is comma separated, but you see that space delimited text as a result of Logger.log(csvFile);  or does Logger.log(csvFile); give another result?

Comment: Hm. It looks like it's recognising commas but not new lines. Looking at the original ',' it's like the last line item on the first line is being joined with the first line item of the second line: cabbages bananas apples carrots
0.006423706
Does this offer any insight towards solving? I think it's the new lines that's the issue

Comment: View > Logs: [15-02-24 16:22:22:880 EST] cabbages,bananas,apples,carrots
0.006423706,0.34396684,0.446078488,0.58361487
0.099325843,0.534487652,0.391869452,0.637707661
0.610335498,0.053597109,0.700272752,0.693743589
0.861971984,0.023244272,0.611117465,0.574383772
0.55353014,0.380635698,0.763808189,0.785754755
0.760590319,0.451239949,0.738469185,0.643373164
0.825044498,0.871200345,0.592596266,0.618885046
0.113003364,0.408002753,0.479294989,0.296725157
0.140159977,0.15718505,0.393824238,0.105260988
0.600180757,0.439033449,0.113330758,0.788

Comment: In that case you'll need to focus on the earlier split,  split("\n"), maybe split("\r") will do the trick.

Comment: Yes!! That was it - split("r"). My day is made, thanks so much. What did that do exactly?

Comment: \r is a "carriage return" character while \n is a "newline character".  Depending on the platform generating the file (Windows, Mac, Linux etc.) the characters used to denote a line ending can be different. In your case you may have "\n\r" which is used by Windows to denote the end of a line, while other platforms may use only \n.   As I understand it the terminology is leftover from the typewriter days.