# How to import csv files to Google Sheets using DriveApp instead of DocsList

Tags: csv, google-apps-script

I have a question similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/26139420/4817369 , except it's not practical for me to use the FileID.

I'd been using this Google Script: 
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/docslist_tutorial
to import csv files into Google Sheets so that I can modify the csv files using other Google Scripts. However, the DocsList feature was officially sun-setted yesterday, and I can't seem to make my code work with DriveApp.

```
function importFromCSV() {
  var fileName = Browser.inputBox("Enter the name of the file in your Docs    List to import (e.g. myFile.csv):");

var files = DocsList.getFiles();
var csvFile = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    if (files[i].getName() == fileName) {
      csvFile = files[i].getContentAsString();
      break;
     }
   }
  var csvData = CSVToArray(csvFile, ",");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  for (var i = 0; i < csvData.length; i++) {
    sheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new      Array(csvData[i]));
  }
}
```

I can't figure out how to actually retrieve a specific file by name once I've searched for it -- I've tried various unsuccessful versions such as:

```
  var fileName = Browser.inputBox("Enter the name of the file in your Docs     List to import (e.g. myFile.csv):");
  var searchFiles = DriveApp.searchFiles(title = fileName);
  while (searchFiles.hasNext()) {
    var file = searchFiles.next();
    Logger.log(file.getName());
  }

  var csvFile = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();// get string content
  Logger.log(csvFile);// check in the logger
  var csvData = CSVToArray_(csvFile);// convert to 2D array
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1,1, csvData.length,  csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);// write to sheet in one single step
    }
```

I have very little experience with coding, so any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your search parameter syntax is missing quotes.  Should be like this:

```
var searchFiles = DriveApp.searchFiles("title = '" + fileName + "'");
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Sandy! That fixed the problem I posted about, although I've now run into a different problem where I get a message that says : Incorrect range width, was 89 but should be 87 (and it says the range width should be 87 no matter how many columns my spreadsheet has...). I can work around that error by using an older version of CSV to Array from //http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1504-Ask-Ben-Parsing-CSV-Strings-With-Javascript-Exec-Regular-Expression-Command.htm, although this older version seems slightly buggy (for example, it always leaves cell A1 empty).

Comment: Post another question for the separate problem.  Include the error msg in the title.  Use the VIEW menu, and the EXECUTION TRANSCRIPT to determine what line the error is coming from.  If you don't know about debugging, learn about it at [Google Documentation - troubleshooting](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints)